# Periodic problem with parallel execution of tests

Tags: java, jenkins, parallel-processing, maven-surefire-plugin

Good afternoon!
I use following stack for implementation automation tests: Java 8, Maven, Jenkins for automation execution of tests.
From time to time (not every time, approximately 3-5% of all executions) I get problem with test(s) during their parallel execution.
Parallel execution is provided by Jenkins and jenkins file. Example structure of jenkins file:

```
stage('First suite'){
            parallel {
                stage('1 test'){
                }
                stage('2 test'){
                }
            }
}
```

Last time I get following error:

```
[ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR]     at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
[ERROR]     at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
[ERROR]     at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SystemPropertyManager.loadProperties(SystemPropertyManager.java:50)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.BooterDeserializer.<init>(BooterDeserializer.java:62)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.setupBooter(ForkedBooter.java:109)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:561)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:548)
```

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) on project webuicheck: There are test failures.
```

```
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

```
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:748)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:265)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1314)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1159)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:932)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
[ERROR]     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
```

I've tried to follow all recommendation concerning:

- updating of maven-surefire-plugin (now I have one of the latest version);
- setting parameters in pom.xml:

```
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <xmlOutputDir>${project.build.directory}/surefire</xmlOutputDir>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <classesDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classesDirectory>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <forkCount>10</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                    <argLine>-Xmx1024m -Xms64m</argLine>
```

I'm desperate and don't know what else to do. Maybe you've faced with the same problem during parallel execution in jenkins (single test execution always complete successfully).
Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: New version 3.0.0-M6 was deployed to Maven Central where we fixed similar issues with NPE. Pls let us know your feedback. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@stru4OK
As I previously said the failure may be caused due to both stages are being overridden in the directory target/surefire. I think we can workaround this problem by setting "tempDir", see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#tempDir

If it would work for you we can confirm my hypothesis. So we have to give it a try.

```
stage('suites') {
        parallel {
            stage('1 test') {
              sh 'mvn clean test -DtempDir=stage1 -Dtest=FirstSuite'
            }
            stage('2 test') {
              sh 'mvn clean test -DtempDir=stage2 -Dtest=SecondSuite'
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT run the Maven build twice in parallel. They will overwrite each other.
This is very bad pattern.

Can you show me what is inside of the stages?

```
            stage('1 test'){
            }
            stage('2 test'){
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

@tibor17, good day! Yes of course:

```
stage('First suite'){
   steps {
       catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
          sh 'mvn -e -Dtest=FirstSuite test'
       }
    }
}
stage('Second suite'){
   steps {
       catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE'){
          sh 'mvn -e -Dtest=SecondSuite test'
       }
    }
}
```

But what did you mean 'overwrite each other'. Finally I get whole Allure report in the end of all stages where my mvn tests are executed and nothing is overwritten. The problem is: seldom (2-3% of all my launching) this leads to error and one or more tests/stages aren't executed and failed with maven-surefire-plugin error.

Comment: Surefire/Failsafe plugins create temporal and persisten files in the target/ directory. They create JAR files, properies files, some other files and it may easily happen that they would be named the same because they are launched at the same time, finallt the target/surefire is deleted by faster run and the slower would have deleted JAR file and it will crash.

Comment: See the documentation for Surefire and you will be able to run these two tests in parallel, see "forkCount" config parameter.

Comment: @tibor1, so you suggest to set parameter forkCount = 2? I've already tried different combinations of surefire parameters in pom.xml and all of them were unsuccessful for me.

Comment: If some parent POM or parent of parent has config parameters for the plugin then it can be harder for you. Skilled Maven developers already know this. Let's generate Effective POM, and see what parameters are merges from parent to your POM, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365633/maven-package-effective-pom

Comment: This tutorial helps https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html  and I can help if you show me the project, but it must be reproducible project.

Comment: Good day! I reworked my tests, using approach above from your sent tutorial and it works without any failures. I mean this approach: mvn -Dtest=FirstSuite test -Dparallel=methods -DthreadCount=6 -DperCoreThreadCount=false when we define maximum thread, what to parallelize etc. But for me very interesting why surefire periodically failed only in approach when you use key work 'parallel' in order to parallelize stages with suites of tests?

Comment: As well for me it's not obvious how using this approach to parallelize for example 2 suites with different tests? With 'parallel' in jenkinsfile it looks easy: parallel of 2 stages with different suites in them. But about second approach? What should I write in maven command? Let's imagine that we have 2 suites: FirstSuite and SecondSuite. How could maven command look like? Thank you, tibor17!

Comment: You can run suites in parallel with the configuration parallel=suites. There are multiple thread-counts (for suites, classes and methods, and the total). Everything is explained in the doc of parameters https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#threadCountClasses

Comment: ok, this I explained works with JUnit 4, means version 4.7 and higher. It does not work with JUnit5 because it has another configuration.

Comment: Also see the doc of the configuration parameter "parallel", there are multiple combinations allowed, https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#parallel

Comment: Good day, tibor17! Thank you for your suggestion and help! Only one thing to be clarified: how in maven command I'd specify certain suite to execute? I mean: I have 10 suites in project. I tend to execute only 2 of them, how could I specify it in maven command? By include/exclude in maven-surefire-plugin and run with parallel=suites? Or somehow it could be specified like: mvn -Dtest=FirstSuite|SecondSuite test parallel=suites ?

Comment: I think you need to have the config which appears in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009232/maven-surefire-junit-test-suite

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon!
I've generated effective POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Cp1251"?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Generated by Maven Help Plugin on 2021-07-15T12:23:27+03:00            -->
<!-- See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/                -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- Effective POM for project 'webuicheck:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT'      -->
<!--                                                                        -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/
xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId></groupId>
  <artifactId>webuicheck</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <allure.version>2.13.9</allure.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.7.M3</aspectj.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
      <version>5.22.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-junit4</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.9</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.19.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.tngtech.junit.dataprovider</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit4-dataprovider</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.24</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
      <version>19.8.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>Central Repository</name>
      <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\src\main\resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <directory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\src\test\resources\properties</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <directory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target</directory>
    <finalName>webuicheck-1.0-SNAPSHOT</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classesDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\classes</classesDirectory>
              <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
              <forkCount>4</forkCount>
              <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
              <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.7.M3/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.M3.jar"</argLine>
              <properties>
                <property>
                  <name>listener</name>
                  <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
                </property>
              </properties>
              <systemProperties>
                <property>allure.results.directory</property>
                <value>target/allure-results</value>
              </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.7.M3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <classesDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\classes</classesDirectory>
          <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
          <forkCount>4</forkCount>
          <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
          <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.7.M3/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.M3.jar"</argLine>
          <properties>
            <property>
              <name>listener</name>
              <value>io.qameta.allure.junit4.AllureJunit4</value>
            </property>
          </properties>
          <systemProperties>
            <property>allure.results.directory</property>
            <value>target/allure-results</value>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportVersion>2.13.9</reportVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>C:\Projects\webuicheck\target\site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>firefox</id>
      <properties>
        <browser>firefox</browser>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>chrome</id>
      <properties>
        <browser>chrome</browser>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>ie</id>
      <properties>
        <browser>ie</browser>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

@tibor17, thanks for this suggestion! I'll check it. Also now I'm test another approach with different target directory for every thread. I define in pom.xml different target directory path:

```
 <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>firstOutputDir</id>
        <build>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/target1/test-classes</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>secondOutputDir</id>
        <build>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/target2/test-classes</directory>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And use different profiles in executed suites:

```
        stage('Tests'){
        parallel {
            stage('FirstSuite'){
                steps {
                    sh 'mvn -e -Dtest=FirstSuite test -PfirstOutputDir'
                }
            }
            stage('SecondSuite'){
                steps {
                    sh 'mvn -e -Dtest=SecondSuite test -PsecondOutputDir'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What do you think about such approach? During last 15-20 execution I didn't face any surefire error. Maybe it's coincidence or maybe solution. Not sure)

Comment: Yes, this would be also the way and maybe better than the workaround in Surefire. The build.directory is not directory for building classes. It should be a parent of the classes dir, so pls give it a try with <directory>${project.basedir}/target1</directory>. This should be correct, IMO. I would personally not use profiles, but property for build.directory with a default value ${project.build.directory}. It is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you, tibor15! I'll check it!