# How most basic pom file get pluginManagement in Effective pom

Tags: maven, effective-pom

Just the most basic pom.xml file 
Effective pom shows that it has pluginManagement with reference to maven-antrun-plugin

From where is it taken ? 
How to avoid this ? 
In bigger context such dependencies are shown as outdated by versions at "mvn clean versions:dependency-updates-report versions:plugin-updates-report", and they are outdated

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T00:58:13-07:00)
Maven home: /opt/maven/default
Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_152/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

$ cat pom.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.my</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>myname</name>
</project>

$ mvn help:effective-pom | grep -A 20 "<pluginManagement"
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>

$ mvn versions:plugin-updates-report -DpluginUpdatesReportFormats=xml && cat target/plugin-updates-report.xml | grep -A 10 "<pluginManagements"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myname 0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.5:plugin-updates-report (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.704 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-13T14:35:15-08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/304M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <pluginManagements>
        <pluginManagement>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <currentVersion>1.3</currentVersion>
            <nextVersion>1.4</nextVersion>
            <minors>
                <minor>1.4</minor>
                <minor>1.5</minor>
                <minor>1.6</minor>
                <minor>1.7</minor>
```

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923954/944849) for a similar question helps.

Comment: You alway inherit from the super pom and you can't avoid it. Like in Java you alway inherit from Object. Apart from that why is it a problem to inherit from it?

Comment: Not a problem, I just tried to check latest versions by versions-maven-plugin , so it was not obvious from where they come and how to override them to keep output of versions-maven-plugin empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all such versions are from super pom 
http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html , pluginManagement should be copied to pom.xml and version are upgraded in pom.xml to latest versions.